# Generic function in VB.Net_forms have as the same control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have some code like this:

```
                    If m_frmParent.Name = "formA" Then
                        Dim formTest = CType(m_frmParent, formA)
                        formTest.pnlHeader.pnlPending.RefreshMedicationMonitoring()
                    End If
```

------------    or

```
                    If m_frmParent.Name = "formB" Then
                        Dim formTest = CType(m_frmParent, formB)
                        formTest.pnlHeader.pnlPending.RefreshMedicationMonitoring()
                    End If
```

these forms have as the same user control **pnlHeader** that contains **pnlPending** user control

> pnlHeader.pnlPending.RefreshMedicationMonitoring()

Please help me change this to generic function that I can use for every form.
Thanks!

Comment: Create an abstract base class which `FormA` and `FormB` inherit. Either put the logic of `RefreshMedicationMonitoring` into the base class or define it as MustInherit and implement it in the child forms. Then call your code directly from `frmParent.pnlHeader.pnlPending.RefreshMedicationMonitoring()` and polymorphis mwill do the rest for you.

Comment: pnlPending is user control in pnlHeader user control too.
Thanks for your solution, but it seem not simple to implement

Comment: Add the user controls to your base class.

Answer (score -1):

Hei try the following :

```
Dim formTest As formB = DirectCast(m_frmParent, formB)
formTest.pnlHeader.pnlPending.RefreshMedicationMonitoring()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering but this is not generic function that I desire

Comment: @Steve should encourage for all

Comment: Your choice, but really against the spirit of the site. If you encourage bad answers, more bad answers will come and the site quality will degrade.